# SO users with high reputation down voted and forced a question to be deleted

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, etiquette, vote-to-delete

Yesterday, a user asked a question regarding variables in JavaScript. He said that he is new in the field. Though the question he asked is not too important, other (high-rep) users downvoted his question and flagged it. Nobody was answering, but he got negative comments. I answered the question and provided a link to let him learn more. Others also wrote negative comments on my answer.

Is there anything wrong in this?

Somebody who is new in the field and asking a question which he might not get answered anywhere else. His question has been deleted.

Does this mean that **only** people who already have clear concepts and good knowledge are able to ask or answer the questions here?

Comment: First:  how do you know it was only high-rep users doing this?  Second:  how do you know the question was flagged?  Third:  if you admit that the question wasn't worth it, what's the *problem* with it being deleted?

Comment: the users with high reputations were only commenting in negative way. Somebody even said to put on**hold** (i don't know what it exactly was) like something..and there about names of 4-5 users were displaying.. Sorry the comments were marked flag there. i accept there is no problem with it being deleted, i myself thinking that this will not let new users to be interact more here. They might feel shy for asking new questions again..

Comment: You need to distinguish between being new at something, and not putting in enough effort when asking a question (both in terms of research beforehand and when asking the question itself). It's entirely feasible to be new at a topic, but still ask a good question. It does take effort though - and I have no problem with that.

Comment: @choxx It's good if these users feel "shy" about asking questions again. It will hopefully make them put more effort into it than they did the first time round

Comment: @Clive but that effort may not be asking question here i think..

Comment: That's fine too @choxx, the internet is a big place; people are free to seek help wherever they see fit. If they want to do it _here_, they just need to be prepared to be judged by their peers right from the word "go". Admittedly that can get out of hand on rare occasions, but for the most part the system works perfectly to weed out the crap that doesn't belong here. As others have said, their is no onus on prior-knowledge here, just on asking a decent question.

Comment: yeah, that is ok.. i am closing my discussion now. thanks for clarify.

Comment: hireps frequently close as duplicate

Answer (score 23):

It doesn't matter what their experience in the field is; if a person faces a problem, they should be prepared to do the **due diligence of research and experimentation** before posing a question before others.

If they don't as deemed by the community, they're actually given a *chance* by having their question put on hold until they can clean it up, and it can get reviewed.

If it's truly irrecoverable, then it makes sense for it to be deleted.

I understand that users can often become discouraged after an occurrence of this, but the real issue is that the user did not ask a question that others felt was useful, well-researched, clear, or any combination of the above.  The site is meant to build a repository of high-quality Q&A; downvotes, flags and deletion are the tools we use to ensure the quality *stays* high.

Comment: i agree with your opinion. but on the other hand it is also not good to directly insult them for being asked such a question. They might be told in a _polite_ manner for doing so or not doing so. After i had given answer, he was having a little feel of _guilty_ as he had done a sin by asking such question(as according to his reply in the commet).

Comment: No one should feel *insulted*, necessarily.  That's not the kind of thing the downvotes/closure should invoke (although it does, and I don't think that all of the well-wishing in the world would fix that entirely).

Comment: I think the community has some hot-heads that wlll go out of their way to throw an insult when a simple downvote/VTC would be enough. I've even caught myself doing it. Downvoting bad content is perfectly OK but kicking someone who is already down is not. It's not clear to me if the OP is concerned about the insults or the downvotes though.

Comment: True that ivarni.... but also some userd get VERY defensive about DV, flags and VTC. How often do ppl show up on meta with one or two downvotes and react as if we went back in time to slap their ancestors?

Comment: @Patrice *"as if we went back in time to bitch slap their ancestors"* - in some cases, I wish we could!

Comment: @jonrsharpe hehe... if only my friend.... if only. I would have a couple of choice words for some of these ancestors... mainly "don't reproduce, you'll do everyone a favor" Luckily.... there ARE some more than decent users on this. We just have to filter out the bad ones...

Comment: Looks like a bit of culture clash was involved here as well. Some cultures, especially Eastern, are [extremely sensitive to negative comments](http://www.mahalo.com/how-to-say-no-in-japanese).